# Changing data with auto increment identifier

Tags: indexeddb

The problem happened is that when I change any data which is as auto increment identifier instead of a change be made and take effect with the same identifier, he creates another with identifier and the changed data. He must only change the data of the identifier that I chose.

```
       var objectStorePC = db.transaction(["tbl_PESSOA_CELULA"], "readwrite").objectStore("tbl_PESSOA_CELULA");
          var requestPC = objectStorePC.get(vetorPessoa[i].key);
          requestPC.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log(event.target.error.message);
          };
          requestPC.onsuccess = function(event) {
            // Obter os valores antigos
            var data = requestPC.result;
            console.log(data);

            // atualizar algum dado
            data.FLG_IDENT_PESSO = $("#slc_VINCULO").val();

            console.log(objectStorePC);
            // Atulizar esse dado no banco
            var requestUpdatePC = requestPC.put(data);
            requestUpdatePC.onerror = function(event) {
              // Tratar erro
            };
            requestUpdatePC.onsuccess = function(event) {
              var w_codigo_celula = sessionStorage.getItem('codigo');
              $wrapper = document.querySelector('#membros');
              $wrapper.innerHTML = "";
              activate_page("#listar_MEMBROS");
              searchmembers(w_codigo_celula);
            };
          };



    TABLESS 01
--------------------
|CODIGO - COD 1    |
|NOME   - person 1 |
|TEXTO  - bababa   |
--------------------
      TABLESS 01
--------------------
|CODIGO - COD 2    |
|NOME   - person 1 |
|TEXTO  - aaaaaaa  |
--------------------
```

Comment: Can you make a stand-alone reproduction? And can you report what output you're seeing? It's difficult to guess without that data. For example, w_codigo is never specified above. And the return value from within the oncomplete handler function would never be seen by other code.

Comment: In truth, the previous problem was solved, the problem was because I was putting the continuation of code in onSuccess and is necessary puts him in onComplete. But I am with another problem when I am changing a given, whose code is with auto increment, instead of changing the field, he saves another, with more data but with the change. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `put()` with an explicit key as the second argument to update a record.

```
var requestUpdatePC = requestPC.put(data, vetorPessoa[i].key);
```

The key generator is only used if an explicit key is not passed.

(Also, please ask a new question rather than replacing an existing question, even if it was answered. It makes the associated comments difficult to understand.)